# Cual es la metodología para que un GUI y sus Widgets puedan adaptarse a cualquier resolución de pantalla?

Tags: tkinter, widget

En esta ocasión quiero preguntarles si conocen o tienen información acerca de cómo puedo ajustar automáticamente un GUI y sus Widgets a cualquier resolución de pantalla manteniendo las distribuciones y los tamaños escalados acorde a cada resolución.

Quiero implementar esta metodología en tkinter.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Puede utilizar el administrador de geometría `pack()` para que los controles se adapten a el estado de la ventana, consulte: (https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/tkinter.html#the-window-manager)

Comment: @JohnDeb, Estoy usando el gestor de geometría place(), extraigo del sistema operativo la resolución de pantalla pero la pregunta está encaminada a si existe una manera de que cuando use por ejemplo una resolución  1920x1080 y luego use una con 640x480 el GUI generado mantenga la estructura y la disposición, que esta no se vea afectada al cambiar de resolución. Lo anterior debido a que con el GUI en el que estoy trabajando cuando cambio de equipo y de resolución los Widgets se salen de la pantalla o quedan mal distribuidos.